# Any solution to use non-guessable links in a program?

Tags: c#, java, javascript

I've been looking for a file hosting site to host my files and my friend offered me a premium account on Box.net.

The problem in this host site (and on many others) is that the links arent guessable, they cant be predicted. That means: If you upload 2 images called "1.jpg" and "2.jpg", the links aren't like

> "www.host.com/omar/1.jpg , www.host.com/omar/2.jpg" ,

instead, they are like

> "www.host.com/qweqwasd , www.host.com/123lqqwje" ..

So I cant use them on my application since I upload a lot of small site and I cant copy each link manually, it will take days.

Is there a way to override this problem in a program? maybe run a script to get all the links on the site?

Comment: Even though UUID is predictable - it could be a good solution for you

Answer (score 2):

When you upload a file, presumably the page shown afterwards gives the link - so just parse that page and extract the link from it.

Just think about how you'd get the link if you were a human, and do the same thing in code. (I assume you're already performing the upload in code.)

Alternatively, use a different file hosting site, which lets you specify the filename.

Comment: No I just drag all the files manually from my PC.. I guess I'll have to use another site. Can you suggest any host site?

Comment: @Omar: No, but web hosting with FTP is reasonably cheap... or just write a program to perform the upload for you.